Can I power a 12-volt LED with a 9-volt supply?
I'd like to install some 1.8 mm LED lights, and a 9 V battery supply would be most convenient.

Would it be okay to run these lights on that supply?
Can I run more than one LED off of the same supply?


Please [edit] your question to include the datasheet (not an Amazon or Ali-what's-it ad page) for the LEDs. The answer depends on the specifications.

If your LED looks like this, then it has a series resistor added. It will be dimmer at 9V. Try it and see if it is acceptable to you.

https://www.amazon.com/EDGELEC-LED-Lights-Emitting-Diodes/dp/B087CWTLNJ
A 9V battery has a capacity of about 500 mAh. If you can measure the current, then you can calculate the life of the battery fairly accurately. If not, assume about 10 mA.
One 9V with 1 LED will last about 50 hours 500/10. Two LED modules in parallel will last half as long, etc.

The 12V LED will have an internal dropping resistor. Running it on 9V should not be a problem, it will just be dimmer. You won’t damage the LED if you try it.
And, yes, you can connect more than one in parallel.

If they're in series string, 3 green, blue or white LED's would drop just a bit over 9 volts. In that case, the string might not light at all.

At 1.8mm being powered by a low-wattage source it's a reasonable assumption that it's a single LED. Again, it won't be damaged if they try it on 9V.

Without further information as the LED datasheet, we could assume you are referring to something like this kind of LED “light”.
If your LED assembly is similar to those ones, then YES, the “LED light” will operate but a little bit dimmer, as they are composed of two electronic components:

The LED (light emitting diode) itself.
A current limiting Resistor.

And in this case, YES, you can run several assemblies in parallel, but it will drain faster your battery.
These two components are connected in series, so the current passing through them is the same and essentially limited by that resistor, usually hidden inside a (black) heat-shrink (tubing).
On a conventional rectifier diode, this voltage drop is ~0.7 V, but to produce visible light, its voltage drop starts from 1.8 V (red) to 2.8~3.2 V (white), or a little bit higher for UV LEDs. This voltage drop in the forward direction is usually named V_forward or Vf.
Now about the current limiting Resistor.  It is calculated as follows:
R = (V_PowerSupply - Vf)/ i_LED
Assuming most small White LEDs operate at 20 mA and have Vf ~= 3 V, then
R = (12 - 3)/0.02 = 450 ohms ; commercial is 470 Ohm, so for 12 V the LED current with a 470R resistor is:
i_12V = 19 mA.
Assuming now the Power supply is a 9V battery, the current at this reduced voltage is a reduced current:
i_9V = 13 mA.
This means a current reduction to 67% and about the same reduction of the nominal brightness, assuming it is a white LED and 12V is the nominal rating.
In case your 1.8 mm LED assembly is similar but has a different color, you will have different Vf, with lightly different current and brightness variations.
In case these assumptions are too much different, then please add more details to your question.
